# Disable scrolling of tableview then textView becomes first responder

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextview

Is it any way to disable scrolling of `tableView` when a `textView` in a cell is touched, or programmatically get triggered?

I tried this:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
[scrollview setContentOffset:scrollview.contentOffset animated:NO];
```

but it does not work always.

I tried to put `setContentOffset` into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Neither this worked.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the textView delegate method "textViewDidBeginEditing:" and then set the scrollEnabled property to NO

Example:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

In your .h

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

And don't forget to set your textView delegate

```
textField.delegate = self; // view controller
```